# Spring Integration Gateway with no arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

On my gateway, I have a method

```
@Gateway
String commsTest();
```

The idea is that I can call commsTest from the bean and use spring integration to wire it up to the service activator that will check comms.

When I do that I get a `receive is not supported, because no pollable reply channel has been configured` error.  I realise that this is because a method with no params means "I am trying to poll a message from the channel"

This is a two part question.

1. What does it mean to poll a message from the channel.
2. How can I get the functionality I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Integration currently has no concept of a message without a payload. By default, a gateway method with no arguments implies you want to receive data (rather than sending data or sending and receiving data).

You can change that default behavior, as described [in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods).

Comment: I think the updated documentation is now at https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods

Comment: Thanks; fixed the link.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, I'm a bit confused. I hit this problem, but I didn't expect to, because I had marked my no-arg gateway interface method with `@Gateway(payloadExpression="''")`. However I still got the error "receive is not supported, because no pollable reply channel has been configured". Replacing `@Gateway(payloadExpression="''")` with `@Payload("''")` fixed the problem. But why the former does not work?? I already use `@Gateway(payloadExpression="<something>")` in other contexts (with methods with 1+ args) and it works well, why do I need to use `@Payload` here instead? Is it on purpose?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments to an answer that is nearly 10 years old!!! Ask a new question showing code, configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell although I believe the topic is exactly this and could be helpful to other people landing here, I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69632638/gatewaypayloadexpression-vs-payload).

Comment: Well, it's clearly not the same - this question is using annotation-based configuration whereas you are using XML (which your comment made no mention of - hence a new question is always better).