# How to call SFTP Outbound Gateway operations in Configuration from Component in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have looked here [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#configuring-with-java-configuration-3) and am unable to get listFiles to work:

```
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser("foo");
        factory.setPassword("foo");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        factory.setTestSession(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {
         @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
         List<File> listFiles();

    }
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new SftpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "'my_remote_dir/'");
    }
```

where in my @Component class I have this:

```
    @Autowired
    MyGateway gateway;

    public void list(){
        List<File> files = gateway.listFiles();
    }
```

when I run this, I get an error `receive is not supported, because no pollable reply channel has been configured`

I assume this is an issue with my knowledge/understanding of integration channels. Perhaps I am missing a bean, but my main goal here is to do replace my current use of the inboundchannel adapter to request files ad hoc instead of continuously polling the fileserver

Comment: Might this be the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790323/spring-integration-gateway-with-no-arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the story mentioned in the [Spring Integration Gateway with no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790323/spring-integration-gateway-with-no-arguments) is definitely related to your problem.

You are missing the fact that `List<File> listFiles()` contract comes without arguments, so it is not clear for the framework what to use for sending to that `sftpChannel`. Therefore it try to call `receive`. But since your `sftpChannel` is not `PollableChannel`, you got that error. Anyway that is a different story and not what you want to get as a reply from sending a message to the `sftpChannel` as you try to do with that gateway contract.

You just need to be more explicit and say what to use as a payload for that no-arg gateway contract.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods. The `@Payload` is an answer for you. Or you can specify a `payloadExpression` on that `@Gateway` annotation or a `defaultPayloadExpression` on the `@MessagingGateway`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but you also could change your no-arg gateway contract to a one-arg contract having nothing to annotate additionally.

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {
     @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
     List<File> listFiles(String remoteDir);

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new SftpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), Command.LS, "payload");
}
```

In your @Component class then you will have:

```
@Autowired
MyGateway gateway;

public void list(){
    List<File> files = gateway.listFiles("'my_remote_dir/'");
}
```