# @Gateway(payloadExpression="..") vs @Payload("...")

Tags: annotations, spring-integration, gateway, payload, xml-configuration

[Spring integration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods) explains that a payload expression must be specified when declaring a gateway from an interface method with no arguments, so that the framework knows what payload should be set on the generated message.
However, if I do the following:

```xml
<int:gateway id="myGateway"
  service-interface="com.example.MyGateway"
  default-request-channel="requestChannel"
  default-reply-channel="replyChannel" />
```

for the following interface:

```java
package com.example;
public interface MyGateway {

    @Gateway(payloadExpression = "''")
    String doSomething();
}
```

this leads to an error: "receive is not supported, because no pollable reply channel has been configured".

This works instead:

```java
public interface MyGateway {

    @Payload("''")
    String doSomething();
}
```

Indeed, the same above documentation specifies that the payload should be specified with either `@Payload` or with `payload-expression` attribute on `method` elements.
However, as a user, I find it quite surprising that setting a payload expression through the `@Gateway` annotation does not work here, especially because the same annotation works in other contexts.

Is this on purpose or an oversight?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why the documentation is confusing, but feel free to suggest improvements.

The `@Gateway` annotation is intended for configuration when using annotation-based configuration

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-configuration-annotations

The docs clearly state to use `@Payload` or `payload-expression` when using XML configuration.

Comment: I've not said the documentation is confusing, I said that the behaviour is surprising. I have other projects in which I declare my gateway in XML with a simple declaration like the above, then I annotate multiple methods within that interface with `@Gateway` and this works perfectly fine. It seems like the problem occurs when such interface has just one method, in which case probably `@Gateway` is simply ignored, or at least its `payloadExpression` value. Compare the behaviour with transformers: it's perfectly fine to declare a transformer in XML and use `@Transformer` to specify which method.

Comment: I see what you mean - the other properties (e.g. requestChannel) work - it should work too https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3648